# Add a default value to form submission in Laravel

Tags: database, laravel, laravel-5, input

In my controller I've got the destination columns and the origin fields for specific data entered in my create function. However, I've got a few default values in here, like below:

```
    $shipment->shipment_billing_status = 1;
    $shipment->created_by = $user_id;
    $shipment->cn_billtoName = request('cn_billtoName');
```

As you can see `$shipment->shipment_billing_status` default value should always be 1. However, in extreme cases, I would like a user to be able to choose (if they need to) between two checkboxes, titled "No Settle" and "No Charge", or their values being 2 and 3.

So in those extreme cases, I want a record to absolutely go to 1 if the "No Settle" or "No Charge" checkboxes aren't selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the default value of an input if it's `null`, like so:

```
$shipment->shipment_billing_status = request("shipment_billing_status", 1);
```

If `request("shipment_billing_status")` is `null`, it'll set `$shipment->shipment_billing_status` to `1`. I don't think this works for `""` (input being sent but set to an empty value), so you may have to handle as such:

```
$billingStatus = request("shipment_billing_status");
if(!$billingStatus || $billingStatus == ""){
   $shipment->shipment_billing_status = 1;
} else {
   $shipment->shipment_billing_status = $billingStatus;
}
```

This should handle cases of sending the value in the `POST` data or omitting it completely.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned `shipment_billing_status` is a checkbox and if any of the checkboxes isn't selected form won't have `shipment_billing_status` field.

A workaround would be:

`$shipment->shipment_billing_status = (isset($request->shipment_billing_status) && !empty($request->shipment_billing_status)) ? $request->shipment_billing_status : 1;`

Explanation: Condition is if $request has shipment_billing_status  field and it's not empty then shipment_billing_status is used, else default value is assigned.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that the name of the check boxes input is status(single case since you're only accepting one status or none), I believe you can do something like this:

```
// Inside the store method.

$status = request('status') ?: 1;

$shipment->shipment_billing_status = $status;
```

Hopefully this should do the trick.

Comment: If a checkbox isn't checked, form won't submit it. Then you will get an error in `$request->status`.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your shipment model and add this line

```html
$table->integer('Billing_status')->default(1);
```

Refresh your migration.

Add this to your view

```html
<div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('Billing_status','Status:') !!}
        {!! Form::select('Billing_status',[1=>'shipment_billing_status',2=>'No Settle', 3=>No chare],null,['class'=>'form-control']) !!}

    </div>
```

This will default shipment_billing_status to 1, if none is selected.
I hope this answers your question.
@Matthew did you try this?